# have error with saxParser on android(not well-formed (invalid token))

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to get  xml file from url link .
This code for android.
I am using SAXParser for doing it.
but I have error:

```
org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 87: not well-formed (invalid token)
```

on this line

```
 saxParser.parse(url.openStream(),handler);
```

my code is:

```
URL url = null;

try {
    url = new URL("toryRss1854.xml");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser saxParser = null;
try {
    saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
    saxParser.parse(url.openStream(),handler);
```

What can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem would appear to be that the XML you are trying to parsing is not UTF-8 so you need to tell SAX which encoding to use.

something like this should work (although not tested this)

```
InputSource is = new InputSource(url.openStream());
is.setEncoding("Cp1255");
parser.parse(is, handler);
```

Comment: The docs say that you don't have to specify an encoding; SaxParser should be able to autodetect the encoding